# ¿Por qué no me corre mi programa en python?

Tags: python

```
class Lampara:
    _ESTADOS = [ "PRENDIDO", "APAGADO"]

    

def __init__(self,esta_encendida):
    self.esta_encendida =esta_encendida


def encender(self):
    self.esta_encendida=True
    self.muestra_lampara()  #cuando se accede de un metodo de clase a otro metodo de clase se accede con self 

def apagar(self):
    self.esta_encendida=False
    self.muestra_lampara() #cuando se accede de un metodo de clase a otro metodo de clase se accede con self


def muestra_lampara(self):
    if self.esta_encendida:
        print( "LA LAMPARA ESTA  : ", self._ESTADOS[0] ) #la variable _Estados esta dentro de la clase entonces se accede atraves de self
    else:
        print( "LA LAMPARA ESTA  : ", self._ESTADOS[1] ) #la variable _Estados esta dentro de la clase entonces se accede atraves de self
 


a=Lampara(False)
a.muestra_lampara()
```

Comment: Recuerda leer el [tour] y tambien [ask]... la forma de agradecer aqui es votando positivamente las respuestas que te sirvieron y marcandolas como aceptadas!!!!

Answer (score 2):

No parece que tengas el nivel de indentación correcto, todas esas definiciones de funciones deberían estar indentadas al mismo nivel que has declarado `_ESTADOS`

Al no estar declaradas al mismo nivel, se interpreta que estás definiendo funciones de forma aislada, en lugar de hacerlas métodos de la clase `Lampara`.

```
class Lampara:
    _ESTADOS = [ "PRENDIDO", "APAGADO"]

    

    def __init__(self,esta_encendida):
        self.esta_encendida =esta_encendida


    def encender(self):
        self.esta_encendida=True
        self.muestra_lampara()  #cuando se accede de un metodo de clase a otro metodo de clase se accede con self 

    def apagar(self):
        self.esta_encendida=False
        self.muestra_lampara() #cuando se accede de un metodo de clase a otro metodo de clase se accede con self


    def muestra_lampara(self):
        if self.esta_encendida:
            print( "LA LAMPARA ESTA  : ", self._ESTADOS[0] ) #la variable _Estados esta dentro de la clase entonces se accede atraves de self
        else:
            print( "LA LAMPARA ESTA  : ", self._ESTADOS[1] ) #la variable _Estados esta dentro de la clase entonces se accede atraves de self
 


a=Lampara(False)
a.muestra_lampara()
```

Comment: gracias amigo te debo una me ayudaste mucho :) :)